# Potential problems from over-allocating truelength more than 1000 times

Tags: r, data.table

**tl;dr: What are potential problems after a truelength over-allocation warning?**

Recently I did something stupid like this:

```
m <- matrix(seq_len(1e4),nrow=10)

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(id=rep(1:2,each=5),m)
DT[,id2:=id]

#Warning message:
#  In `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(id2, id)) :
#  tl (2002) is greater than 1000 items over-allocated (ncol = 1001). 
#     If you didn't set the datatable.alloccol option very large, 
#     please report this to datatable-help including the result of sessionInfo().

DT[,lapply(.SD,mean),by=id2]
```

After some searching it became apparent that the warning resulted from adding a column by reference to a data.table with too many columns and I found some rather technical explanations (e.g., [this](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/datatable-help/2012-August/001260.html)), which I probably don't fully understand.

I know that I can avoid the issue (e.g., use `data.table(id=rep(1:2,each=5),stack(as.data.frame(m)))`), but I wonder if I should expect problems subsequent to such a warning (other than the obvious performance disadvantage from working with a wide format data.table).

```
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
  [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
  [1] data.table_1.8.8 fortunes_1.5-0
```

Comment: +1 too. This came up recently. The answer was to change `options()$datatable.alloccol`. But I can't find it on datatable-help or in S.O. Does search in S.O. exclude comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question. By default in v1.8.8 :

```
> options()$datatable.alloccol
max(100, 2 * ncol(DT))
```

That's probably not the best default. Try changing it :

```
options(datatable.alloccol = quote(max(100L, ncol(DT)+64L))
```

UPDATE: I've now changed the default in v1.8.9 to that.

That option just controls how many spare column pointer slots are allocated so that `:=` can add columns by reference.

---

From NOTES in [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) for v1.8.9

> - The default for `datatable.alloccol` has changed from `max(100L, 2L*ncol(DT))` to `max(100L, ncol(DT)+64L)`. And a pointer to `?truelength` has been added to an error message as sugggested and thanks to Roland :
>             [Potential problems from over-allocating truelength more than 1000 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436356/potential-problems-from-over-allocating-truelength-more-than-1000-times)

Comment: Actually, I was quite happy to be warned. This was part of a simulation and ncol was related to my number of replications. I tested with few replications, everything was fine and I only received the warning when I tried a larger n. The warning enabled me to realize there was a possibilty to improve performance. Changing the option is not a bad idea, but I suggest to put a pointer to `?data.table::truelength` in the warning and add a somewhat simple explanation there.